# Laravel como enviar una imagen por correo

Tags: php, html, laravel

estoy enviando correos con laravel y todo bien, solo que tambien ocupo enviar imagenes y cuando llegan al correo muestra el nombre de la imagen pero la imagen no alguien sabe a que se debe ?

este es mi controlador por el cual guardo los datos de los inputs, documento vendria siendo la imagen

```
public function getMail(Request $request){
    $data = [ 'name' => $request['name'],
    'email' => $request['email'],
    'tel' => $request['tel'],
    'domicilio' => $request['domicilio'],
    'puesto' => $request['puesto'],     
    'documento' => $request['documento']
];
    Mail::to('emshot41@gmail.com')->send(new TestMail1($data));
    return view("bolsa")->with('Sus datos se enviaron correctamente');
   
}
```

Comment: Eso depende de cómo estés construyendo la vista de tu email que se envía, por favor completa tu pregunta con el código que falta, así será más fácil ayudarte

Comment: Mira bro esta es la vista que se manda al email el documento seria la imagen, pero solo me manda el nombre de la imagen

`Bolsa de trabajo <br>
Mi nombre es: {{$name}} <br>
Mi telefono: {{$tel}} <br>
Mi domicilio: {{$domicilio}}<br>
Mi correo: {{$email}} <br>
El puesto que solicitio: {{$puesto}} <br>
{{$documento}}" `